# Valid selector in css

Tags: css

```
#customers tr.alt td 
{
color:#000000;
background-color:#EAF2D3;
}
```

`#customers` is the `id` of a `table`.  Since I'm new to CSS, is the above method a valid selector? In CSS I have only found `element element` selectors.  But here in the question there are three elements: `table tr td`.  I have not found an example of the three element selector.  So does the three element selector exist in CSS?

Comment: yes this works. im not sure if this was worthy of a stackoverflow question. You can have as many selectors as you want.

Comment: It is absolutely fine

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can combine as many [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors) as necessary, and the selector you posted simply styles

any `<td>` thats within a `<tr>` with the class="alt" and is within an element with the ID "customers"

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

The selector is valid, since the CSS selector syntax allows a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) that “is made up of two or more selectors separated by white space”. This is the case in the CSS 2.1 specification, and CSS3 won’t change this.

Technically, `#customers tr.alt td` does not not contain three elements but three selectors, though it can only match an element that is part of a structure containing three nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a valid CSS selector. You can combine as many as you want.